# Exotic Spice & Tea Shop Location

Tags: grimm, real-location

Was the location or address of the Exotic Spice & Tea Shop in the television show Grimm ever shown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Exotic Spice & Tea Shop**

The actual location of this building in Portland is: 100 block of NW 2nd Ave Portland, OR

These scenes utilized the historic Rich Hotel building at 205 Couch.

[image]

The Innovative Housing site has some photos of Rich Hotel building renovations, as well as a few from Grimm filming.

[image: Spice Shop]

*Spice Shop on nbc.com/grimm*

There is an awesome [interactive map](http://www.mysouthwaterfront.com/p/grimm-1-map.html) which lists all of the locations from Season One. All of this information comes from the [South Waterfront Blog](http://www.mysouthwaterfront.com/p/grimm-index.html) in Portland OR.

Comment: Thank you! I tried going through some episodes but could not get a clear shot.